# How to create new Object of child type from parent method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I might not be asking this question right... But my class relationship is as follows:

```
export class ParentClass {
  someProperty: string;

  constructor(){}

  duplicate() {
    const dup = new this; // doesn't work for obvious reasons
    return dup; 
  }
}

export class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
}
```

Because ultimately I want both of these situations to work and be the type that they originally started as:

```
const shouldBeParent: ParentClass = new ParentClass().duplicate();
const shouldBeChild: ChildClass = new ChildClass().duplicate();
```

Is there a way that I can infer a constructor about an object itself and create a new instance from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
class ParentClass {
  str = 'parent'
  constructor(){}

  duplicate() {
     // return new (<any>this.constructor); as more generic way
     return new (<typeof ParentClass>this.constructor);
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
  str = 'child'
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
}

const shouldBeParent: ParentClass = new ParentClass().duplicate();
const shouldBeChild: ChildClass = new ChildClass().duplicate();

console.log(shouldBeParent.str) // parent
console.log(shouldBeChild.str) // child
```

Comment: I added `: this` to the end of the hypothetical `duplicate()` function to get the type hinting correct as well. Had to use the `<any>` decorator in the return function as well. But this works! Thanks much!